# nil-coalescing operator causes compiler to report ambiguity

Tags: ios, swift

I'd like to understand why the expanded method works while the nil-coalescing operator version tells that there is some ambiguity trying to compile it.

```
typealias SendBlock = ([NSArray]) -> Void

var callbacks = [SendBlock]()

func functionWithArgs(callback: SendBlock?) {
    callbacks.append(callback ?? { _ in })
}


func functionWithArgsExpanded(callback: SendBlock?) {
    if let cb = callback {
        callbacks.append(cb)
    } else {
        callbacks.append({ _ in })
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really mean `([NSArray])`??? An array of NSArray??????

Comment: That doesn't seem to be too much relevant for this problem but thanks for pointing this out to me as I corrected it in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s because of the `@autoclosure` used on the rhs argument of `??`.  Something about that means it doesn’t like actually receiving a closure as the type of the thing being coalesced.

Just to demonstrate the location of the issue (don’t do this as a workaround), if you redefine a version of `??` without it, it’s fine:

```
typealias SendBlock = () -> Void

var callbacks = [SendBlock]()

infix operator !! { }
func !!<T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: T)->T {
    return optional != nil ? optional! : defaultValue
}


func functionWithArgs(callback: SendBlock?) {
    callbacks.append( callback !! { _ in })
}

functionWithArgs { _ in println("blah") }

// just to prove it works… prints “blah”
for x in callbacks { x() }
```

But if you amend the operator to use an `@autoclosure`:

```
func !!<T>(optional: T?, @autoclosure defaultValue: ()->T)->T {
    return optional != nil ? optional! : defaultValue()
}
```

You get your error:

> error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
>
> ```
>    callbacks.append( callback !! { _ in })
>                      ^
> ```

I’d say this is a bug and you should [file a report](http://bugreport.apple.com/).  In the mean-time your workaround is probably the best you’ll do.

Comment: What did they gain here by attaching the `@autoclosure` attribute in the first place? Is it to prevent premature evaluation?

Comment: @matt yep, it’s so `??` gets short-circuiting like `||` or `&&`.  If the left-hand side isn’t nil, the right-hand side is never evaluated, so if the right-hand side value was produced by an expensive function call or invalid (or one that had side effects… shudder) it would never run.

Comment: So, just to clarify for the OP, you are not _recommending_ rewriting without `@autoclosure`, as it is important.

Comment: @matt oh I see, no, not advocating it, was just to illustrate the location of the problem (which certainly seems like a Swift bug to me). have edited to avoid confusion, thx

Comment: From Apple Radar, I just got this: "Engineering has determined that your bug report (21275448) is a duplicate of another issue (19237339) and will be closed."

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a bug in the compiler. It works just fine if you substitute String every place you have SendBlock.

Evidently, the compiler chokes on the use of the nil-coalescing operator with an Optional wrapping a function type. You get a more revealing error if you write it like this:

```
func functionWithArgs(callback: SendBlock?) {
    let sb : SendBlock = { _ in }
    callbacks.append(callback ?? sb)
}
```

The error reads: "Binary operator `??` cannot be applied to operands of type `SendBlock?` and `SendBlock`." To which one wants to reply: Of *course* it can! Those are *exactly* the sorts of operand to which it *can* be applied: an Optional and its unwrapped form.

Comment: Filed a bug on Apple bug reporter site: [21275448]

Comment: Thanks for doing that!